# Basic crypt login verification

Tags: php, mysql

So I have a basic database, passwords are hashed using just the basic crypt() function (not good practice, right? but still).

I'm now trying to make a login page. This is my basic code.

```
if (isset($_POST['username'])
 && isset($_POST['input_password'])
 && !empty($_POST['username'])
 && !empty($_POST['input_password'])) {
    $username = trim($_POST['username']);
    $input_password = trim($_POST['input_password']);

    $sql = "SELECT username, password FROM registration WHERE username=? && password=?";
```

I'm really struggling with this. I could do a login with basic text as the password, could get it to work. But the verifying aspect inherent with hashes is throwing me.

I understand I need to do something akin to:

```
if(crypt($input_password, $db_pass)==$db_pass) //plus the username stuff
    echo 'Logged in!';
}
```

Do I need to do a separate SELECT query first to get the password from the entered username? And THEN verify the entered password with the database password through crypt?

So like:

```
$sql = "SELECT username, password FROM registration WHERE username=?";
$stmt = $db -> prepare($sql);
$stmt -> bind_param('s', $username);
$stmt -> execute();

$stmt -> bind_result($db_user, $db_pass);
$stmt -> fetch();

  if(crypt($input_password, $db_pass)==$db_pass) //plus the username stuff
        echo 'Logged in!';
    }else{
        echo 'Not logged in';
  }
```

Would that be the right way? Getting the password directly from the database just by the username doesn't seem very safe. But I cant think of any other way.

Note: This isn't for practical use, just education.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. You need to get the password from the db first, as you need to hash the POSTed password with the same salt stored in the DB.

Comment: Yes that is exactly how you do it. There is no security issue - the password hash is simply used internally to verify the user

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](http://laravel.com/docs/security) built-in.

Comment: Thank-you all! And I wont be writing my own @tadman, I just wanted to get a grasp on the concept so I could practise making my own login systems. :)

Comment: Good to know. There's at least a dozen things you need to get absolutely right or your "login system" ends up being the exact opposite, a way to bypass security. Proper hashing, XSS, and CSRF are just the immediate concerns, all good to know about, but best to learn from solid examples, not random tutorials.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to check if the passwords are the same in your `if` statement, the SQL query is sufficient.

It is sufficient to see if the retrieved row count is >= 1.

Best practice is to save a hashed version of a password in the database and to then use a SELECT query to find if the username and hashed password is the same as the supplied credentials.

Comment: it is needed to retrieve the password from the db first to be able to hash the POSTed password with the same salt the original password was stored

Answer (score -1):

My opinion would be that you should qualify the the POST better than with isset and !empty before using them in a query.

A better approach would be to generate the hash for the password and use the hash in the SELECT query then compare the user name.

The reason being this way you take SQL Injection out of the equation. For the same reason I also, when applicable,  require a numeric value (e.g. last 4, phone) qualify it with `intval($_POST['number'])`.

My preferred hash is `$hash =  hash('ripemd320',$password);`

I do not know if it still stands true today, but at the time I researched hash algorithms ripemd320 was the one that had never been cracked.

Even so, I still check the input values to see if they posted anything that contains the SQL that is typically used for SQL injection:

```
  $strike1 = preg_match_all('/\x2C/',$inputValue,$matches, PREG_SET_ORDER); 
  $strike2 = preg_match_all('/[\x21-\x2F]|[\x3A-\x40]|[\x5B-\x60]|[\x7B-\x7F]/',$inputValue,$matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
  $strike3 =  preg_match_all('/COALESCE|0x|like|regex|mid|select|delete|drop|insert|do|call|replace|update|infile|lock|set|from|into|show|table|kill|reset/i',$inputValue,$matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

Keep in mind I am old and have been doing this a long time. So yes my code may use depreciated PHP.

I also watch for Brute Force attacks.
this code is from my early days and could be improved.  But it works.

```
      $sql = "SELECT `ip`,`TimeStamp`  FROM `access` WHERE `ip` LIKE '$ip'  AND `TimeStamp`  > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP order by `TimeStamp` ASC";
      $results = @mysql_query($sql);
      $rows = mysql_num_rows($results);
      if ($rows == 1) {
        $ipCount = 1;
        $timeCount = abs(strtotime($row[1]) - time());
        $timeMin = $time;
        $timeMax = $time;
      }
      $row = @mysql_fetch_array($results, MYSQL_NUM);

  if ($rowCount > 1) {
    $saveIP[$ipCount++] = $row[0];
    $saveTime[$timeCount++] = strtotime($row[1]);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results, MYSQL_NUM)) {
      $saveTime[$timeCount] = strtotime($row[1]);
      $time = $saveTime[$timeCount] - $saveTime[$timeCount - 1];
      if ($time > $timeMax){
         $timeMax = $time;
       }
      if ($time < $timeMin){
         $timeMin = $time;
       }
      $rowCount += $row[0];
      if ( !in_array($row[0],$saveIP)) {
         $saveIP[$ipCount++] = $row[0];
         $saveIP = $row[0];
         $ipCount++;

      }
    }     
  }
```

And if I find unacceptable behavior:

```
@mysql_query("INSERT INTO `_portal`.`Banned` (`ip`, `TimeStamp`,`Strikes`, `Attributes`) VALUES ('$ip', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, $alert);");
```

Especially on a shared Server it is wise not to put the `mysql_connect()`  in the public script leaving the db name and password exposed if the server is misconfigured where PHP is served as MIME Type text/plain.  Not that uncommon.  And on a shared server I have been able to change the MIME Type for other users to text/plain using .  Opps, not going to publish that code.

To connect I use something like
 `include('/home/user/secureStorage/P7gAv2fH4pU.php');`

When access to a script is administrative I only allow access from my IP.

```
 if ((hash('ripemd320',$passcode) == '6732f3c024fe3c3c1ccd7dbe5d0fa7d4a53c516f800707bb86a9017c1e1646d9d4a2d7adc56a505d') && (substr($ip,0,11)  == '152.30.52.72' || $ip == '72.3.150.55' || $ip == '17.162.23.21' )){
      $admin = true;
    }
```

Comment: "My preferred hash is..." Please, don't let personal preference weigh in here. This is a [solved problem with best practices to follow](http://www.phptherightway.com/#password_hashing). Your rampant use of the wickedly obsolete `mysql_query` method and error suppressing YOLO operator `@` is also severely misguided.

Comment: Pot calling the kettle black? "severely misguided"  isn't that a rude injection of your own personal preference?  I've been doing this since before you were born. Apparently you did not read the post because I pointed out the code was very old and used depreciated PHP.  Severely Misunderstood.

Comment: Can you explain why you're posting old and deprecated PHP code in the form of an answer? The question here uses `mysqli`, so you're completely ignoring that. I'm not here to get into a pissing contest, how long you've been programming isn't the least bit relevant here. I'm just vigilant about stomping out obsolete practices in the hopes they will stop being picked up by new programmers. Answers like this encourage people to be sloppy and make mistakes that can be exploited.

Comment: I'm old and what life I have left is too short.  Feel free to edit.  I'm not real fond of self appointed Grammar Nazis either.  If someone is too stupid to know to add an i, they shouldn't be programming anyway.

Comment: What you do in your own code base is your concern. Here I think we should try and set better examples. That's all I'm asking for. This isn't a case of people being "too stupid", but not knowing better in the first place because nobody has told them otherwise. The search results for "php mysql" are extremely discouraging, a whole museum of very bad ideas.